# Independence of transformed variables

Tags: probability

There are two independent variables X and Y. Y is an input for non deterministic algorithm f, and the output of f(Y) is Z. How to prove that X and Z are independent?

Comment: You have to specify in what way $f$ is non deterministic. Why can't $f(Y)=X+Y$ for example? Do you mean that $f$ is non deterministic and independent of $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y$ (real-valued) random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}[X \in B, Z \in C] &= \mathbb{P}[X \in B, Y \in f^{-1}(B)] = \mathbb{P}[X \in B] \cdot \mathbb{P}[Y \in f^{-1}(B)] \\ &= \mathbb{P}[X \in B] \cdot \mathbb{P}[Z \in C] \end{align*}$$

for Borel sets $B,C$. This proves the independence of $Z=f(Y)$ and $X$. (Note that $f^{-1}(B)$ denotes the preimage of $B$ under $f$, there does not necessarily exist a inverse function.)